# Adding background map to GeoNetwork from GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wms, geonetwork

I use GeoNetwork 3.0.2 ... Is it possible to remove the default background map and is there a way to add a background map from GeoServer, using WMS?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change config-viewer.xml file. You can also change default zoom and position of loaded map.

For example mine for testing looks like that, but WMS is a little weird. When I change base layer it disappear from background layers.

```
<ows-context:OWSContext xmlns:ows-context="http://www.opengis.net/ows-context"
                        xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
                        version="0.3.1" id="ows-context-ex-1-v3">
  <ows-context:General>
    <ows:BoundingBox crs="EPSG:3857">
      <ows:LowerCorner>1531645.1727783617 5723757.552050567</ows:LowerCorner>
      <ows:UpperCorner>1822564.5024317426 5871433.890697529</ows:UpperCorner>
    </ows:BoundingBox>
  </ows-context:General>
  <ows-context:ResourceList>
    <ows-context:Layer name="{type=mapquest}"
                       group="Background layers"
                       hidden="true"
                       opacity="1">
      <ows:Title>MapQuest</ows:Title>
    </ows-context:Layer>
    <ows-context:Layer name="{type=osm}"
                       group="Background layers"
                       hidden="true"
                       opacity="1">
      <ows:Title>OpenStreetMap
      </ows:Title>
    </ows-context:Layer>
    <ows-context:Layer name="{type=wmts,name=elf_basemap}" 
                       group="Background layers" 
                       hidden="true" 
                       opacity="1"> 
      <ows:Title>ELF Basemap</ows:Title> 
      <ows-context:Server service="urn:ogc:serviceType:WMTS"> 
        <ows-context:OnlineResource xlink:href="http://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_wmts" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/> 
      </ows-context:Server> 
    </ows-context:Layer>
    <ows-context:Layer name="0" 
                       group="Background layers" 
                       hidden="false" 
                       opacity="1"> 
      <ows:Title>DOF5</ows:Title> 
      <ows-context:Server service="urn:ogc:serviceType:WMS"> 
        <ows-context:OnlineResource xlink:href="http://copernicus.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/GioLandPublic/EU_DEM/MapServer/WmsServer" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/> 
      </ows-context:Server> 
    </ows-context:Layer>
    <!-- <ows-context:Layer name="{type=bing_aerial}"
                       group="Background layers"
                       hidden="true"
                       opacity="1">
      <ows:Title>Bing Aerial</ows:Title>
    </ows-context:Layer> -->
  </ows-context:ResourceList>
</ows-context:OWSContext>
```

Comment: That is not valid for GeoNetwork 3+.

Comment: Just wondering how is it then working for me using geonetwork 3.0.2.0? Can you provide me one valid configuration (with my data above) that works because I don't know how this json need to be formatted.

Comment: You are right, if you configure GeoNetwork to use ows-context, this file is useful.

Answer (score 2):

On the settings (geonetwork/portal/eng/admin.console#/settings/system) you can find a json string that defines the map on Map -> Configuration for maps

If that is not enough for you, you can modify the javascript files directly:
http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/customizing-application/search-ui/configdefault.html#viewer-settings

Since the documentation is a little quiet on the format of the required URL, it should look like:

```
http://machine:port/path/to/service?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.1.0&LAYERS=osopen&STYLES=default&SRS={srs}&BBOX={minx},{miny},{maxx},{maxy}&WIDTH={width}&HEIGHT={height}&FORMAT=image/png
```

Comment: I still can't switch to those layers though